# Why does the "for" loop skip elements from a list?

Tags: python

I was doing a kind of simple Python exercise, the idea was to create a function that adds the numbers of a list. The problem is that when I run it the `for` loop skips several integers and I don't know why.

```
def simplearraysum(ar):
    sum = 0
    for number in ar:
        sum = sum + number
        ar.remove(number)
    return sum


list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11]

print(simplearraysum(list))
```

The output is 14, but it should be 31.

Comment: Why is the code modifying *the same list* being iterated? (Yes, that’s the answer. Perhaps a *copy* of the list could be created and iterated, or perhaps a *new* list could be created for the result.)

Comment: An easier way to do this is just type the list, and in the next line type ```print(sum(list))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modifying the list when it is being iterated. The `for` loop will take care of the elements in the list. Just comment the line and you will get the correct output:

```py
def simplearraysum(ar):
    sum = 0
    for number in ar:
        sum = sum + number
        #ar.remove(number)
    return sum


list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11]

print(simplearraysum(list))
```